# How to delete files in Draw.IO

Tags: app.diagrams.net

While practicing and learning how to use Draw.IO, I created a lot of flowcharts, etc. that I never bothered to give a name to.  When I select 'OPEN', I see a list of those files with the name 'Untitled Diagram'.  Now that I know what I am doing and want to get rid of them, how do I delete them?

Answer (score 3):

Delete them in the [Google Drive UI](http://drive.google.com) as you would for any other Google Drive file.